# Astronomy Symbols in ConteXt

Tags: context

I sticked to the explanation here:
http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Symbols
but the minimal example

```
\usesymbols[was]
\setupsymbolset[wasy astronomy]
\starttext
\symbol[mercury]
\stoptext
```

Only shows the word "mercury". What am I missing?

Edit: Also not working with:

```
\usesymbols[mvs]
\setupsymbolset[astronomic]
\starttext
\symbol[Mercury]
\stoptext
```

I get the error:

```
fonts           > defining > forced type 'ttf' of 'marvosym' not found
fonts           > defining > font with asked name 'marvosym' is not found using lookup 'file'
fonts           > defining > unknown font 'marvosym', loading aborted
```

But ttf-marvosym is installed, texlive-fonts-recommened is installed and all folder are exported to OSFONTDIR

Comment: The `Waldi Symbols` aren’t available in MkIV. To get a mercury symbol you can use the `Martin Vogel` or `Font Awesome` symbols.

Comment: Still not working. Seems to be a problem that Luatex is not seeing the font. But I don't understand why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works just fine here with TL 2016

```
mtx-context     | ConTeXt Process Management 0.63
mtx-context     |
mtx-context     | main context file: /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/context.mkiv
mtx-context     | current version: 2016.05.17 19:20
```

The example

```
\usesymbols[mvs]
\setupsymbolset[astronomic]
\starttext
\symbol[Mercury]
\stoptext
```

produces

[image]

Please check whether you installed ConTeXt correctly.